# No encuentra librería después de pip install raylib

Tags: python

Instale raylib en Python con `pip install raylib`, pero cuando escribo el código , me sale como si no lo hubiera instalado.

Este fue un comando que encontré en la pagina oficial de raylib, pero cuando lo puse en mi código no funcionó

```
from pyray import *
init_window(800, 450, "Hello")
while not window_should_close():
    begin_drawing()
    clear_background(WHITE)
    draw_text("Hello world", 190, 200, 20, VIOLET)
    end_drawing()
close_window()
```

Comment: Puede que tengas Python 2 y 3 instalado. Prueba con `pip3 install raylib`

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir a la pregunta el error concreto que te dió? Por otro lado, asegúrate que la instalación fue correcta. Requiere la compilación de un módulo en C, por lo que tienes que tener un entorno de desarrollo preparado para este lenguaje.

Comment: si pongo el error que me dio pues verias mi informacion en la carpeta,  pero si te puedo decir que en el powershell cmd me dice que ya esta instalado pero cuando inicio el codigo me dice :  <module>
    from pyray import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyray'